# Iterate over list of dictionaries with nested list in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I tried many existing filters but I wasn't able to find a solution. I want to perform some action (let's say `debug`) on each element of the inner list inside a list of dictionaries together with key of that dictionary.

Input data:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - debug: msg='{{ mykey_item }} with {{ inner_list_item }}'
     loop: '{{ something_here }}'
  vars:
    example:
      - mykey: key1
        inner_list:
          - one
          - two
      - mykey: key2
        inner_list:
          - three
          - four
```

Expected output:

```
key1 with one
key1 with two
key2 with three
key2 with four
```

Comment: What's wrong with `subelements`?

Comment: Oh. It's doing a strange thing, but I guess the result still can be used. (it's produce `item=[{u'inner_list': [u'one', u'two'], u'mykey': u'key1'}, u'one']`, ..., `item=[{u'inner_list': [u'three', u'four'], u'mykey': u'key2'}, u'four']`).